# Doxygen - make call graph show implicit call to constructors and overloaded operator calls?

Tags: doxygen

Is there currently a way to make Doxygen to show implicit calls to constructors and/or calls to overloaded operators inside a call graph? The only function calls shown in the call graphs are just normal function calls. I am guessing Doxygen don't have this capability yet, but maybe there is some obscure option somewhere that I missed.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding **overloaded functions**, as late as 2011, Dimitri van Heesch (who rewrote the code for Doxygen), [said the following](http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/Wrong-call-caller-graphs-with-overloaded-functions-td1531.html):

> The code parser, which is responsible for generating the cross
>   references and call graphs, does not look at the parameters of
>   functions. So in case of overloading it does not necessarily link to
>   the right method unfortunately.
>
> Not something that is easy to fix I'm afraid.

Regarding **constructors**, the Doxygen issue list at its GitHub repository contains [an issue](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6508) "C++ Calls to constructor not shown in call graph" (#6508). As of the time I'm writing this (November 2018), one contributor has pushed a proposed patch, but it has not been pulled into the GitHub repository.